# Copying a color image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to copy a particular area of image1 to image2. For that I am using the following code.

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        if(OD(i,j)==0)
            result(i,j,1)=Original(i,j,1);
            result(i,j,2)=Original(i,j,2);
            result(i,j,3)=Original(i,j,3);
        end
    end
end
```

This is fine and pretty good.[image] Just to reduce the execution time, I tried the following

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        if(OD(i,j)==0)
            result(i,j)=Original(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

This is giving some unnecessary color on the result image. You can see pink color in this image.
[image]
Also when I try

```
result(OD==0)=Original;
```

I am getting the following error.

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
```

But both the result and Original images are of same sizes. I don't understand why this is occurring. Can some one tell me what is the difference between them and why the outputs are like that.

Comment: In the second loop, why do you not set all three dimensions to zero?

Comment: Can you post the output of `size(Original)` please?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
result(OD==0)=Original(OD==0);
```

otherwise you try to copy the whole Original image into a (sub) area of the result image.

Comment: This is not helping. This is also giving some unnecessary color on the result image in interested area.(Same output as second loop in the question)

Comment: Can you provide a small dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I think one image in Matlab have 3 spaces: R, G, B with (,,1) (,,2) (,,3). Problem of you: result(i,j)=Original(i,j);

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you haven't set all colours (dimensions) to zero.

Why not vectorise it

```
 [R,C] = find(OD==0); % // Get the coordinates where OD is zero
 result(R,C,:)=Original(R,C,:); % // copy the data over at those coordinates
```

Timings between the the approach above and the original is below. The timings might look slow but bear in mind that it is not on the fastest computer and should be seen as a relative measure.

```
+----------+------------+
| Original | Vectorised |
+----------+------------+
| 3.663 s  | 0.246 (s)  |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: @Saipavan579 I doubt it very much. There must be some other issues with your code then. I hope you don't put this inside the loops? This replaces both of your loops.

Comment: I didn't keep this code inside loop. I compared these two lines with my serial code(1st snippet in the question)

Comment: @Saipavan579 I modified the answer but the for loop is still the slowest.

Comment: Result image should not be affected when OD==1. I have to change only the part of result where OD==0. OD is binary image only.

Comment: @Saipavan579 I added images to demonstrate the effect. I just picked an arbitrary rectangle as OD but that should obviously be your own mask. The mask is `1` everywhere except for the rectangle so you are multiplying the original image with `0` where the black rectangle is and `1` everywhere else. This means that the only part that will be affected is where `OD=0`. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: You haven't understand it properly. In place of that rectangle pixels I have to keep pixels from another image. There are three images. `result`,`OD(mask)`,`original`. I have to replace pixels in the `result` with the pixels in `original` based on condition `OD(pixel)==0`. Remaining pixels in the `result` should be as it is. If you are still unclear I can post all the three images and required result.

Comment: @Saipavan579 I have modified it again and I hope this satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I don't know why? but timings for `loop` and `yourAnswer` are '0.012902 ' and `0.442406` respectively in my system.

Comment: I've tried it on two different computers with R2013a and Octave 3.8.2 and  I get the same timings as previously. Could it be that you are mixing the timings up?